# Dictionary of Dictionary in swift

Tags: swift

I am studing swift.

I found out `dictionary` is like `hash` for PHP or some other langage.

then how can I make `dictionary` of `dictionary`??

I have data like this

```
key:J name:jhon age:28
key:L name:lee age:30 
key:O name:oam age:35
```

Now I write down the code like this in appDelegate.

```
var p1: [String: String] = ["name" : "john","age" : "28"]
var p2: [String: String] = ["name" : "lee","age" : "30"]
var p3: [String: String] = ["name" : "oam","age" : "35"]

var people: [String: Dictionary] = ["J":p1,"L":p2,"O":P3]
```

it shows error like this

```
AppDelegate.swift:47:60: Cannot convert value of type '[String : String]' to expected dictionary value type 'Dictionary'
```

Comment: The error is about `song1` and I can't see `song1` anywhere in the provided code. I think the error does not have anything to do with this question.

Comment: this error is not related to your dictionary code that you've shared here. I usually see this when `self` is not fully initialized. Can you share your init code?

Comment: that error has nothing to do with how you create the dictionary...

Comment: sorry I miss typo song1 -> p1

Comment: The error in not related to the acual lines you posted, please post more of your code. When loading this code into a playground it fails with a different error message, but if I change the last line to var people: [String: [String: String]] = ["J":p1,"L":p2,"O":p3] it will compile. (You need to write the exact type of the inner dictionary, not just Dictionary)

Comment: @mildal thanks very much , This is what I want to know.

Comment: And sorry for making confuision first miss type to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
 var people: [String: Dictionary] = ["J":p1,"L":p2,"O":P3]
```

with

```
 var people: [String: [String:String ]] = ["J":p1,"L":p2,"O":p3] // it's p3 not P3
```

And you can't add the another dictionary property in top level of property initializers. put into `viewDidLoad` or some method.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use it like a dictionary from a scripting language try setting the type to `[String: Any]`.

If you specifically want your example to work, try `[String: [String: String]]`

Comment: Kinda perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
var people: [String: [String : String]] = ["J":p1,"L":p2,"O":P3]
```

You need to explicitly define the type for your `Dictionary`, which in this case is `[String : String]`

Answer (score 1):

When creating a dictionary of dictionary in swift you need to rerfrer to the exact typed inner dictionary, not just Dictionary. The following line will work fine:

```
var people: [String: [String: String]] = ["J":p1,"L":p2,"O":p3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

- You cannot run the code to create `people` on the top level of the class. You have to put it into a method and create `people` as an empty dictionary.
- As `Dictionary` is a generic type in Swift you have to add the actual type.

  ```
  let p1 = ["name" : "john","age" : "28"]
  let p2 = ["name" : "lee","age" : "30"]
  let p3 = ["name" : "oam","age" : "35"]

  var people = [String : Dictionary<String,String>]() // or [String : [String:String}]()

  func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad() 
      people = ["J":p1,"L":p2,"O":p3]
  }
  ```

There is no need to annotate the type of the 3 dictionaries. The compiler can infer the type. And if they are not going to be changed, declare them as constant (`let`).

Comment: AFAIK nothing indicates he was putting the declaration at the top level. But you are right he probably doesn't even need the type annotations.

Comment: @ハセン Orginally before having edited the question the OP posted the typical *Cannot use instance member .. property initializers run before `self` is available* error.